# SQL Subquery or Group BY to return Distinct values of a certain column?

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by, subquery

I am running into an issue where I know I am close to a solution but I cannot get the right data to come back or am getting errors on the queries.

Basically what I want to do is to select values from a single table based on the following: I want them based on an employee name I supply and I want them to return DISTINCT Account Numbers for that employee(sometimes the same account number is listed more than one time...I only want one row of data from each duplicate account number).

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Employees WHERE EmpName = 'Mary Johnson' GROUP BY AccountID
```

-This returns an error saying I don't have an aggregate for the column EmployeeID(which isn't a calculated column, so why is it asking for an aggregate??)

Then I tried a subquery:

```
SELECT EmployeeID, EmpName, Department, Position, (SELECT DISTINCT AccountID From Employees) AS AcctID FROM Employees WHERE EmpName = 'Mary Johnson'
```

-This gives me an error saying AT Most one record can be returned(I'm in Access).

I know there has to be a solution to what I am looking for---Currently If I do a full query just on EmpName it returns 30 records, however, 23 of them have a duplicate AccountID, so there should only be 7 records that return with a DISTINCT AccountID.

How can I achieve this via SQL?

Here is an Example:

```
ID(PK)       EmpName          AcctID      Department   Position    EmpId
------       --------        ---------   --------     --------    ------
 1           Mary Johnson     1234          IT          Tech       226663
 2           Mary Johnson     1234          IT          Tech       226663
 3           Mary Johnson     1234          IT          Tech       226663
 4           Mary Johnson     2345          IT          Tech       226663
 5           John James       23442         Banking     Teller     445645
 6           Jame Tabor       1234          HR          Manager    234555
```

In the example above I want to do an SQL Query to get the rows back with the AccountId's for Mary Johnson that are DISTINCT.  So We would get back 2 rows  Mary Johnson 1234 and Mary Johnson 2345, ignoring the other 2 rows that Mary Johnson has with duplicate AccountIDs of 1234 and the other rows with employees not named Mary Johnson

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text.

Comment: Edit your question and show the columns in `Employee`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really easy to do in MS Access -- it lacks `row_number()`.  One method is to use another column that uniquely identifies each row that has the same `AccountID`:

```
select e.*
from Employees as e
where e.?? = (select max(e2.??)
              from Employees as e2
              where e2.AccountId = e.AccountId and e2.empName = e.empName
             );
```

The `??` is for the column that uniquely identifies the rows.

If you only care about two columns, then use `select distinct`:

```
select distinct e.empName, e.AccountId
from employees as e;
```

You an add a `where` clause to either query to restrict to a single employee.  However, it doesn't make sense to me that a table called `Employees` would have multiple rows for a single employee name (except in the rare case of people with the same names).

Comment: Its just a generic example, I can't give you the information I am working with as its restricted.  I do also have an ID as a primary key in the table

Comment: Ugh...works in SQL Fiddle perfectly fine, when I test in Access it ends up freezing Access...

Answer (score -1):

The reason you are getting the error about "you can only return one row" is because you are using a subquery to feed into a record row. In that case, you are searching for distinct AcctIDs for Mary Johnson, she has two distinct ones, so the query fails. If you used MIN(AcctID) that query would work fine. Therefore, this will work:

```
SELECT EmployeeID, EmpName, Department, Position, MIN(AccountID )
FROM Employees 
WHERE EmpName = 'Mary Johnson'
GROUP BY EmployeeID, EmpName, Department, Position
```

The next question you need to ask yourself is WHICH AccountID do you want to see? You can switch to MAX, but if you have three values and you want the middle one, that will be a lot harder to solve. But, the above query will at least give you a working result.

**EDIT:**

That should give you only one row assuming you have identical information for Mary Johnson. If you are getting 24 it means you have different entries For empname, department, position, or employeeid. If you want to see all AccountIDs associated with Mary Johnson, use this:

```
SELECT EmployeeID, MIN(EmpName), AccountID, MIN(Department) AS Department, MIN(Position) AS Position
FROM Employees 
WHERE EmpName = 'Mary Johnson'
GROUP BY EmployeeID, AccountID
```

Comment: This does not give me the correct results...It returns 24 records instead of 7

Comment: See my edit. Also, your table is not set up to follow good relational database structuring rules. That is the root cause of your issues here.

Comment: Also, if you didn't get the results you expected, you should clarify in the comments and original post, not just downvote it. That's actually really rude and disrespectful.